# Add multiple numbers to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays. They look like this:

```
array price = 14.60, 39.00
```

and

```
array quantity = 10, 5
```

(quantity is the quantity of items the user want to buy - 10 items from `productA` and 5 of `productB`)

Now I want loop through the variables to multiply the price with the quantity.

Like :

```
14,60 * 10
```

and

```
39,00 * 5
```

and add the two results to the `endPrice` variable.

I get the quantity array like this:

```
$('.quantity').change(function () {
    quantitys = $('input[type=number]').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
});
```

and the different prices like this:

```
var prices = $('.priceCell').map(function () {
    return parseFloat($(this).html().trim());
}).get();
```

And that's what I tried:

```
var endPrice = 0;
for (var q = 0; q < quantitys.length; q++) {
    for (var p = 0; p < prices.length; p++) {
    endPrice = quantitys[q] * prices[p];
    }
}

alert(endPrice);
```

Well, that haven't worked for me so well. Can someone help me there? Doesn't matter if the solution is pure JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Have you checked if `quantitys` and `prices` are as you expect them to be?

Comment: Yeah I did and they exactly like in the question

Comment: I can only assume that you're getting syntax errors with your variable assignments (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`) since neither of those assignments declare, or initialise, an Array. To do so they should look like: `price = [14.60, 39.00];` Note the surrounding square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1st problem

You were using nested loops thus **every** quantity would be multiplied by **every** prices. You only need one loop.

## 2nd problem

You were using `endPrice = ...`. This will override the `endPrice` every time you go through this line. You need to use `+=` that will add to the current `enbPrice`

```js
var prices = [14.60, 39.00];
var quantities = [10,5];
var endPrice = 0;

for(let i=0, l=prices.length;i<l;i++){
  endPrice += prices[i] * quantities[i];  
}

console.log(endPrice);
```

**EDIT**

OP need to have separated totals. (See @David Thomas's answer)

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)

```js
var prices = [14.60, 39.00];
var quantities = [10, 5];

var totals = prices.map((p, index) => p * quantities[index]);

console.log(totals);
```

Comment: Nice ! This works! Is there a way to add the two different results to another way? Like : anotherarray = [ (result of 14.60 * 10), (result of 36.00*5) ]. This would help me alot. I'm still new to JS :)

Comment: @WellNo: absolutely, that's exactly what my answer does.

Comment: I copy and paste that little snippit for seperated values but this haven't worked for me. I don't really understand what (p, index) is..

Comment: @WellNo Check the link to the documentation. This is a callback with `p` as the current value and `index` as the index. -- What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: Forget what I was said. Works fine now hehe.

Answer (score 3):

You are using two loops while you should only use one. Also, add to `endPrice` by using `+=`:

```
var endPrice = 0;
for (var q = 0; q < quantitys.length; q++) {
    endPrice += parseFloat(quantitys[q]) * parseFloat(prices[q]);
}

alert(endPrice);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the double loop for this. This multiplies *every* price with *every* quantity. What you want to do is this:

```
var endPrice = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < quantitys.length; i++) {
    endPrice += quantitys[i] * prices[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To multiply every price in one Array by the number held at the same index in a second Array I'd recommend:

```
var price = [14.60, 39.00],
    quantity = [10, 5],

    // here we iterate over the price Array, using
    // Array.prototype.map() in order to return a
    // new Array:
    totals = price.map(

        // p: the current array-element of
        //    the Array of prices,
        // index: the index of the current
        // array-element of the Array.

        // using an Arrow function to
        // multiply the price ('p') by
        // the value held in the quantity
        // Array at the same index:
        (p,index) => p * quantity[index]
    );

// logging the created 'totals' Array to the console:
console.log(totals); // [146,195]

// logging the created Array, after joining its
// elements together to form a String with values
// separated with a ',' character:
console.log(totals.join(',')); // "146,195"
```

Comment: I copy and paste your code and tried it out but I get multiple problems with it. My console is also empty.. no error message at all. 

var totals = prices.map((p, index) => p * quantitys[index]);

Comment: Forget what I said, works perfect now! Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Close, you're missing `+=` instead of `=`

```
endPrice += quantitys[q] * prices[p];
```

Dependent on your values, you may also want to parse them, so:

```
endPrice += (parseInt(quantitys[q]) * prices[p]) // you're already parsing prices;
```

Edit with more information in comments:

Because of the way your code is, they prices are on the same row as the quantities, so they'll be the same. So, the new code will be...

```
for (var q = 0; q < quantitys.length; q++) {
    endPrice += parseInt(quantitys[q]) * prices[q];
}
```

Comment: I also tried it with += but this gave me a weird value back ( 808.5 ). And the right result would be around 350 :/

Answer (score 1):

```js
const prices = [14.60, 39.00];
const qty = [10, 5];

const endPrice = prices.reduce((total, price, i) => total + price * qty[i], 0);

console.log(endPrice);
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!